# R Student-t (location 0 scale 1)

Tags: r, statistics, mle

So I've read about fitting student-t in R using MLE but it always appears to be the case that location and scale parameters are of the utmost interest. I just want to fit a student-t (as described by wikipedia) to data that is usually considered to be distributed like a standard normal so I can assume the mean is 0 and the scale is 1. How can I do this is R?

Comment: Precisely, you use MLE to find the "right" parameters of the student-t distribution. If you want an even easier way to fit a "t" distribution using maximum likelihood estimation, you can look at `fitdistr` from the MASS package.

Answer (score 1):

If you "assume" your location and scale parameters, you are not "fitting" a distribution to the data, you are simply assuming that the data follows a certain distribution.

"Fitting" a distribution to some data means finding "appropriate" parameters of this distribution so that it "accurately" models your data. Maximum likelihood estimation is a method to find point-estimates of the parameters based on some data.

The easiest way to fit a classic distribution such as student-t is to use the function fitdistr from the MASS package, which uses MLE.

Assuming you have some data:

```
library("MASS")
# generating some data following a normal dist
x <- rnorm(100)

# fitting a t dist, although this makes little sense here
# since you know x comes from a normal dist...
fitdistr(x, densfun="t", df=length(x)-1)
```

Note that the student-t density is parameterised by location `m`, scale `s` and the degrees of freedom df. df is not tuned, but is set based on the data.

The output of fitdistr contains the fitted values for m and s. If you store the output in an object, you can access programmatically to all sorts of info about the fit.

The question now is whether fitting a t dist is what you really want to do. If the data is normal, why would you want to fit a t dist?

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for the function [t.test](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/ttest.html).

```
x <- rnorm(100)
t.test(x)
```

I put a sample [here](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=17ctbEVS)

## EDIT

I think I misunderstood your question slightly. Use t.test for hypothesis testing about the location of your population density (here a standard normal).

As for fitting the parameters of a t distribution, you should not do this unless your data comes from a t distribution. If you know your data comes from a standard normal distribution, you already know the location and scale parameters, so what's the sense?